# How to pull and push file from a remote host to another remote host?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy a file from one remote host and place it on another remote host. I use three hosts, the master and two others nodes. However, my playbook keeps skipping over the host that is suppose to copy the actual file.

Want is suppose to happen is the file is first fetched from "10.1.1.1" to the ansible master, then from there it is copied over to "10.2.2.2".

Please if you know of any better way to accomplish this, let me know. I am not sure if sending it to the master node is best practice.

**Playbook:**

```
      run_once: yes
      fetch: src=/home/ups/passExample.sh dest=/home/ups/ flat=yes

    - name: Copy the file from master to mwiapp02
      copy: src=/home/ups/passExample.sh dest=/home/ups
      when: ansible_hostname == '10.2.2.2'
```

**Inventory File:**

```
10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2
```

***Error:**

```
TASK [Copy the file from master to mwiapp02] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.1.1.1]
skipping: [10.2.2.2]
```

Comment: Can you copy the contents of hosts file?

Comment: @PrakashKrishna Turns out, since I am using VM's, the ansible_hostname for all of them are called "dchpvm". So that is why it is being skipped. Do you know of any way I can specify in the fetch module the exact ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ansible_ssh_host` instead of `ansible_hostname`.

Comment: Can you please post the hosts file where you are mentioning IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Try ansible_all_ipv4_addresses or ansible_default_ipv4.address